# collapsing repeated observations counting sum of a given variable to a certain point

Tags: r

```
id  bleed   episodes
J1  0   0
JI  0   1
J1  0   1
JI  yes 0
J2  0   0
J2  0   1
J2  0   1
J2  0   1
J2  yes 0
J2  0   0
J3  0   1
J3  0   1
J3  0   0
J3  0   1
J3  yes 0
J3  0   0
```

I want to collapse this data to count the number of episodes up to where a bleed occurs for every individual to look like this

```
id  episodes
J1  2
J2  3
J3  3
```

The observations were made at different times, I didn’t include the time variable, but its weekly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this sample input

```
dd <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("J1", "J2", "J3"), class = "factor"), 
    bleed = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
    episodes = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("id", "bleed", "episodes"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

You can accomplish this task with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

dd %>% group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(bleed_count=cumsum(bleed=="yes")) %>%
    filter(bleed_count==0) %>%
    summarize(episodes = sum(episodes))
```

Use use `cumsum()` on a Boolean value to track when the bleed occurs. Then we sum only those values before the first bleed

Comment: perfect, suppose I had other variables with same ID and same observations and I want them to remain, how do i go about it

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,  .(episodes = sum(episodes[seq_len(which(bleed == "yes")[1])])), id]
#    id episodes
#1: J1        2
#2: J2        3
#3: J3        3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("J1", "J1", "J1", "J1", "J2", "J2", "J2", 
"J2", "J2", "J2", "J3", "J3", "J3", "J3", "J3", "J3"), bleed = c("0", 
"0", "0", "yes", "0", "0", "0", "0", "yes", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "yes", "0"), episodes = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("id", "bleed", "episodes"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```